# How can I achieve delayed component projection in Angular 6?

Tags: angular

[Here is the code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/delayed-projection-test?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) I will be referencing. It is a stackblitz project stripped down to the bare components necessary to explain the problem.

So what I would like to do, is be able to pass a component as a child of another component, but this parent component should be able to prevent it's creation until it decides it wants to create it. In the example, app.component.html file I am passing `<app-action>` as a child to `<app-projector>` and I want `<app-projector>` to be able to hold off on the actual creation of `<app-action>` for a while.

The `<app-projector>` component cannot actually reference the `ActionComponent` ts class via ContentChildren because it should be able to be any component.

My current stackblitz example tries to use `<ng-template>` in the projector component but as you can see there it does create the component and run the component lifecycle functions before the projector component decides to actually render the content in the template. I would like to make it so that until we are ready to render the component passed as content we do not start the lifecycle functions or create the component.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The source of your problem is that `<ng-content>` happens during build-time - any component you project into it will be created during build-time rather than during run-time! ([source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PTwKhxLZ3jI)) This is why, in your StackBlitz, the `<app-action>` component **already starts counting** before it is even displayed on screen. Instead of using `<ng-content>` for delayed content projection, you should use the following method.

(Check out the [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/delayed-projection-9jxyaf)  to see that it works as expected)

---

**Create a structural directive**

A structural directive is a directive that changes the DOM *structure*, such as by adding, removing, or manipulating elements. For example, `ngIf` and `ngFor` are structural directives. The thing about structural directives is that Angular automatically "converts" the *host element* of the directive into an `<ng-template>` if you put an asterisk `*` prefix in front of the directive. For example, this:

```
<div *ngIf="myCondition">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

...is automatically converted into this by Angular:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="myCondition">
  <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
</ng-template>
```

So, if we created our own structural directive called `delayedContent` and applied it to a component/element like `<app-action>`:

```
<app-action *delayedContent></app-action>
```

...then it would be converted to this:

```
<ng-template delayedContent>
   <app-action></app-action>
</ng-template>
```

Here is the TS file for `delayedContent`:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[delayedContent]'
})
export class DelayedContentDirective {
  constructor(templateRef: TemplateRef<void>, projector: ProjectorComponent) {
    projector.allDelayedContent.push(templateRef);
  }
}
```

Here I can use `TemplateRef` to get a reference to the `<ng-template>` element generated by Angular, and then push the `TemplateRef` to an array in the parent `<app-projector>` component.

In the `<app-projector>` component, we can now take the `TemplateRefs` and display them in your `<ng-container>`. Now your `<app-action>` component will only be created when `createEmbeddedView()` is called, so it will start counting from 0 when it is displayed (rather than from 3).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-projector',
  templateUrl: './projector.component.html'
})
export class ProjectorComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  // All the TemplateRefs to the delayed content will be stored in this array
  allDelayedContent: TemplateRef<void>[] = [];

  @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) _container: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Show this after 3 seconds
    setTimeout(() => {
      this._container.createEmbeddedView(this.allDelayedContent[0]);
    }, 3000)

    // You can add other elements to the `allDelayedContent` array and show them here
    // Show this after 5 seconds
    setTimeout(() => {
      this._container.createEmbeddedView(this.allDelayedContent[1]);
    }, 5000)

    // Show this after 7 seconds
    setTimeout(() => {
      this._container.createEmbeddedView(this.allDelayedContent[2]);
    }, 7000)
  }
}
```

---

Check out this [second StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/delayed-projection-alternative-iqysb7). It has a modified version of the `delayedContent` structural directive which lets you specify the delay time directly in the HTML like this:

```
<app-projector>
  <app-action *delayedContent="3000"></app-action>
  <div *delayedContent="2000">Some delayed content</div>
  <div *delayedContent="6000">More delayed content</div>
<app-projector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Show the projected component conditionally with `*ngIf`

app-projector.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="showContent">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

---

Define the `showContent` variable and set it to true whenever you want to create and show the projected component.

app-projector.component.ts

```
public showContent = false;
```

Comment: This doesn't work; because of the way `<ng-content>` works, `<app-action>` will be created when you run the program, rather than it being created at a later time. Try running [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/delayed-projection-test-6cn25x) (based on the code in your answer), and you'll see that `<app-action>` will start counting _before_ it is even shown on screen, which is the exact problem the OP wants to solve.

Answer (score -1):

As much as I can understand from your question is, you want to display your child component after a while. Please change your code as below and try to run, hope this will be helpful.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef, ContentChild } from '@angular/core';
import {ActionComponent} from '../action/action.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-projector',
  templateUrl: './projector.component.html'
})
export class ProjectorComponent implements OnInit {
displayChild = false;
  @ViewChild('template', { read: TemplateRef }) _template: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) _container: ViewContainerRef;


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.displayChild = true;
      console.log("Display " + this.displayChild);
      this._container.createEmbeddedView(this._template);
    },5000)
  }


}
```

```html
<ng-template #template>
  <ng-content *ngIf="displayChild"></ng-content>
</ng-template>

<ng-container #container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: For this to work you need to add static: true to each view child